# Find Second Minimum Number in List

Tags: python, python-2.7

Need to sort the list

```
students = [['Prashant',32],['Pallavi',36],['Dheeraj',39],['pawan',36],
['Shivam',40],['amir',36]]
```

I need list of student with second minimum score in alphabetically sorted:
ex. fist min = 32 = prashant
so second min = 36 
i need list of that student with score 36 with alphabetically sorted:

`output: Amir
            Pallavi
            Pawan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fairly useful to use `heapq.nsmallest` to get the two smallest scores and then take the larger of the two:

```
students = [['Prashant',32],['Pallavi',36],['Dheeraj',39],['pawan',36],
['Shivam',40],['amir',36]]

import heapq
```

To avoid filtering the list twice group all the names by their scores:

```
by_scores = {}
for n,s in students:
    by_scores.setdefault(s, []).append(n)

second_lowest_score = max(heapq.nsmallest(2, by_scores.keys()))
for name in sorted(by_scores[second_lowest_score]):
    print name
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
>>> students
[['Prashant', 32], ['Pallavi', 36], ['Dheeraj', 39], ['Pawan', 36], ['Shivam', 40], ['Amir', 36]]
```

How about:

```
>>> sorted(st3 for st3 in students if
...   st3[1]==min(st2[1] for st2 in students if st2[1]!=min(st[1] for st in students)))
[['Amir', 36], ['Pallavi', 36], ['Pawan', 36]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple keys when sorting:

```
>>> import operator
>>> students = [['Prashant',32],['Pallavi',36],['Dheeraj',39],['Pawan',36],['Shivam',40],['Amir',36]]
>>> sorted_students = sorted(students, key=operator.itemgetter(1, 0))
>>> sorted_students
[['Prashant', 32], ['Amir', 36], ['Pallavi', 36], ['Pawan', 36], ['Dheeraj', 39], ['Shivam', 40]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This one :

```
students = [['Prashant',32],['Pallavi',36],['Dheeraj',39],['Pawan',36],['Shivam',40],['Amir',36]]
names = []
s = set(i[1] for i in students)
sec_min =  sorted(s)[1]
for j in students:
if (j[1] == sec_min):
    names.append (j[0])
names.sort()
print names
```

Answer (score 0):

```
students = [['Prashant',32],['Pallavi',36],['Dheeraj',39],['pawan',36],['Shivam',40],['amir',36]]

stud = dict()

'''
Save students list into a dictionay with score as dictionary index
i.e {32: 'Prashant', 36: 'Pallavi','pawan','amir'
'''
for student in students:
    if student[1] in stud:
    stud[student[1]].append(student[0])
else:
    stud[student[1]]=[]
    stud[student[1]].append(student[0])


sorted_names=sorted(list(map(str.title,stud[sorted(stud.keys())[1]])))
for student in sorted_names:
    print(student)

'''
BREAKDOWN
scores = sorted(stud.keys())
second_score = scores[1]
second_score_students = stud[second_score]
second_score_students = list(map(str.title,second_score_students))
sorted_names=sorted(second_score_students)
'''
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    sorted_names=sorted(list(map(str.title,stud[sorted(stud.keys())[1]])))
IndexError: list index out of range